# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Dialog.create

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have created custom Dialog layout. When user press on the button the dialog is shown. Android version lollipop shows me the dialog perfectly but in case of lower version than lollipop it throws me error.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button click;
    private Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.equals(click))
                {
                    dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.check_in_weight_dialog);
                    dialog.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my custom dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check In Weight"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="20">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Current Weight"
            android:background="@drawable/editext_border"
            android:id="@+id/edtCheckInWhgt"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btncheckin"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: on which version Androyd check except lolipop?

Comment: Only on lollipop it shows. On rest of the version it throws error.

Comment: `Dialog.create()` was added in API level 21. You can't use this method with an Android version lower than Android5.0 (lolipop)

Comment: Thanks man worked ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dialog.create();
```

this is for lolipop only. Remove this line

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ,It works fine (Lolipop)

```
custom_dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);
custom_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((0xff000000)));
custom_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
custom_dialog.setCancelable(false);
custom_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.check_in_weight_dialog);
custom_dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
custom_dialog.show();
```

Or Remove `dialog.create();`

```
dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.check_in_weight_dialog);
                  dialog.show();
```

Comment: remove dialog.create();